# Connecting to other instances of Hyper-V Manager in domain

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-authentication, windows-8

I have a test environment that I host from my computer. I have configured an external switch so that it can be accessed by others. Windows 8 Enterprise and Hyper-V Manager Version: 6.2.9200.16384

If we take a look inside the Hyper-V Manager we can see that we have: "Hyper-V Manager" and under it we have connection to the local machine. We also have the possibility to add a new connection by connecting a server.

I've tried to connect to another local machine in the domain but i get the following error message:

" *An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "Name". Check that the Virtual Machine Management Service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.* "

The service is running, **what kind of authorization do i need?** (I can see the other machine in the network).

I'm thankful for all help!

Comment: Are the machines in question (the Hyper-V servers and the management clients) in the same AD domain? If so, you probably just need to enable Remote Management on the Hyper-V server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably haven't configured WMI and DCOM for remoting on your client and server. John Howard wrote a [series of blog articles](http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2008/03/28/part-1-hyper-v-remote-management-you-do-not-have-the-requested-permission-to-complete-this-task-contact-the-administrator-of-the-authorization-policy-for-the-computer-computername.aspx) explaining how to connect to a non-AD integrated hyper-V server remotely and several of these steps apply to doing the same in hyper-V as well.

The simplest way to do that is to download the [Hyper-V remote management configuration utility](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote) script from MSDN's code sample site and follow the instructions on [John's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/11/14/configure-hyper-v-remote-management-in-seconds.aspx).